# Java web-services (Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens)

Tags: java, jersey

I am new in Java Webservices i am following this link to make my first java web-service "http://www.java2blog.com/2013/04/create-restful-web-servicesjax-rs-using.html" but i am getting strange error "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens", the code is pasted below. any help from anyone highly appreciate in advance.

```
package org.arpit.javapostsforlearning.webservices.client;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;

public class ConversionServiceClient {
    static final String REST_URI = "http://localhost:8080/RESTfulWebServiceExample";
    static final String INCH_TO_FEET = "/ConversionService/InchToFeet/";
    static final String FEET_TO_INCH = "/ConversionService/FeetToInch/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int inch=12;
        int feet=2;

        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        WebResource service = client.resource(REST_URI);

        WebResource addService = service.path("rest").path(INCH_TO_FEET+inch);
        System.out.println("INCH_TO_FEET Response: " + getResponse(addService));
        System.out.println("INCH_TO_FEET Output as XML: " + getOutputAsXML(addService));
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");

        WebResource subService = service.path("rest").path(FEET_TO_INCH+feet);
        System.out.println("FEET_TO_INCH Response: " + getResponse(subService));
        System.out.println("FEET_TO_INCH Output as XML: " + getOutputAsXML(subService));
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");

    }

    private static String getResponse(WebResource service) {
        return service.accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(ClientResponse.class).toString();
    }

    private static String getOutputAsXML(WebResource service) {
        return service.accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(String.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: When/where/how do you get that error?

Comment: i have just copy paste the code from the given link and got that error. but now i am manage to know what the issue is on this link there is space before all the lines and that why the error is showing. Thanks Dave Newton for response.

Comment: What I meant was that just saying "you got this error" isn't  specific enough-it's best to provide more comprehensive information so people can help more easily. For example, you could ask a mechanic to fix your car and say only "it makes a grinding noise", but their first question will be "When dies it make the noise?" Be forthcoming early in the process-it saves everybody's time.

Comment: yeah sorry i am new in stackoverflow in a sense i did't use this site to solve my problem, i will try my best for next time to give best information about my problem thanks, in this problem i am just getting this error so that's i dont know why this happening so that whay i pasted the link from where i got that code.